# Exercises in programming style with Scala

Tags: scala, coding-style

I've started to read the "[Exercises in programming style](https://github.com/crista/exercises-in-programming-style)" book recently and one of the tasks there is to implement each programming style in a language of your choice. I decided to go with Scala (I'm fairly new to it) and I'm already stuck with the first "good old school" style. The constraints are:

> - Very small amount of primary memory, typically orders of magnitude   smaller than the data that needs to be processed/generated.    (The example sets the limit to 1024 cells)
> - No labels -- i.e. no variable names or tagged memory addresses. All we have is memory that is addressable with numbers.

Original example (which reads a file line by line and counts the words) is in Python and goes like this:

```
data = []
data.append([])    # data[1] is line (max 80 characters)
data.append(None)  # data[2] is index of the start_char of word
data.append(0)     # data[3] is index on characters, i = 0
data.append(False) # data[4] is flag indicating if word was found
data.append('')    # data[5] is the word
data.append('')    # data[6] is word,NNNN
data.append(0)     # data[7] is frequency
...

f = open(sys.argv[1])
# Loop over input file's lines
while True:
    data[1] = [f.readline()]
...
```

So we see there are some variables (f and data) but the main idea is to keep it to a minimum and use python array as a bunch of "memory addresses".

Is it even possible to implement old-school-programming style (no variable names or tagged memory addresses) in Scala? Specifically is there a way to avoid "line" variable when reading file content?

```
for (line <- Source.fromFile("example.txt").getLines) {
  println(line.toUpperCase)
}
```

Reading the file content into an array similar to the original example doesn't work because it's doesn't have an extractor (*value data is not a case class, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq member*).

P.S. I'm very well aware of the fact that the whole task is probably a 5-liner in Scala but that's not the point.

Comment: You may want to look at using a map.  You should be able to apply a function over the array of words that will count the number of words in that line, and then use a reduce to sum all of those.  Don't have something to test it with, so just leaving a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can abstain from introducing variables besides the `data`-array (and solve the problem imperative-style). Simply put everything into your array instead of assigning it to a local variable.

Obviously, the code will be a nightmare, because the array won't be typed and you won't have any meaningful names for any of your data, but I'm assuming that's what you're aiming for with this exercise.

```
import scala.io.Source

/**
 * data 0 : file as line iterator
 * data 1 : index of first unused data cell
 * data 2 : current line
 * data 3 : index of the first letter of the current word
 * data 4 : index of the last letter of the current word
 * data 5 : current word
 * data 6 : temp index to find already initialized words
 * data 7 : flag: Word found
 * data 8, 10, 12, ... words
 * data 9, 11, 13, ... frequencies
 */
object GoodOldSchool {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val data: Array[Any] = new Array[Any](1024)
    data(0) = Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines()
    data(1) = 8 // first free cell
    while (data(0).asInstanceOf[Iterator[String]].hasNext) {
      data(2) = data(0).asInstanceOf[Iterator[String]].next()
      data(3) = 0 // index first letter of current word
      data(4) = 0 // index last letter of current word
      // find index last letter of current word
      while (data(4).asInstanceOf[Int] < data(2).asInstanceOf[String].length) {
        // find the next space (we ignore punctuation)
        while (data(4).asInstanceOf[Int] < data(2).asInstanceOf[String].length && data(2).asInstanceOf[String].charAt(data(4).asInstanceOf[Int]) != ' ') {
          data(4) = data(4).asInstanceOf[Int] + 1
        }
        data(5) = data(2).asInstanceOf[String].substring(data(3).asInstanceOf[Int], data(4).asInstanceOf[Int]) // current word
        data(6) = 8 // cell index
        data(7) = false // word already found
        8 until data(1).asInstanceOf[Int] by 2 foreach { _ =>
          // Here, we do a case-sensitive word comparison
          if (data(5) == data(data(6).asInstanceOf[Int])) {
            data(data(6).asInstanceOf[Int] + 1) = data(data(6).asInstanceOf[Int] + 1).asInstanceOf[Int] + 1 // increment frequency
            data(7) = true
          }
          data(6) = data(6).asInstanceOf[Int] + 2
        }
        if (data(7) == false) {
          // create new frequency, because word was not discovered before
          data(data(1).asInstanceOf[Int]) = data(5) // set word
          data(data(1).asInstanceOf[Int] + 1) = 1 // set frequency
          data(1) = data(1).asInstanceOf[Int] + 2 // used up two cells, update index of next free cell
        }
        // move to next word
        data(3) = data(4).asInstanceOf[Int] + 1
        data(4) = data(3)
      }
    }

    data foreach println // let's have a look at our result
  }

}
```

Comment: That's probably is exactly how it supposed to look like for this exercise! ^^

Answer (score 0):

To get the total words count in the given file, the following scala code can be used:

```
Source.fromFile("example.txt")
      .getLines.map { line => line.trim.split(" ").length}
      .reduceLeft { _ + _ }
```

Comment: This is nice, but not necessarily the "good-old-style" where u have to parse the line, character by character, searching for the word start and end...